# Use ImageSearch to control the menus of Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, autohotkey

Did someone try to use ImageSearch to control the menus of google sheets? It's somehow failing me.

I simulated a right click on column A and then tried to find the option to change the size of the column with `ImageSearch`. I even put *n to 60 and that kind of worked but with the unpleasant side effect that it took at least 2 seconds for AutoHotkey to detect the image/word and then click on it. Does this work for your or do you have the same problem as me?

This is my ImageSearch function:

```
ImageSearchFunction(ImagePath){
        start := A_TickCount
        Loop {
            ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, 1373, 775, *60 %ImagePath%
            totalTime := stop - start
            stop := A_TickCount
            ClickX := FoundX + 15
            ClickY := FoundY + 15
            if ErrorLevel = 0
                {
                break
                }
            else if totalTime > 3000
                {
                MsgBox, Something went wrong!
                exit
                }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ImageSearch, but could you explain more about what you're trying to achieve? It may be easier/more appropriate to use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setColumnWidth(Integer,Integer)) depending on your goals

Comment: Yes! I have done this as well, and it also sucks. I changed it to just go to the same spot within screen every time and that usually works even though my two monitors are different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with a mousemove to the same place within the window every time and it works more consistently than image search did:

```
!e:: ; "Tools" is at x540 y245
{

CoordMode, Mouse, Relative
MouseMove, 540, 250,0
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos 
MouseClick  
MouseMove, xpos, ypos+125,3
MouseClick
    return
}
```

ImageSearch will work for a day or two and then just not work, no idea why. this one I have to adjust a lot less often.

edit. this script goes to "tools > script editor"